# Solving differential equations of the form $f'(x)=f(x+1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve differential equations of the following form:

$\frac{df}{dx} = f(x+1)$

Comment: Not really sure about solving because this isn't my field, but after a quick Google search, these are a specific type of differential equations known as Functional Differential Equations (FDEs) https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_differential_equation

Comment: Because I cannor edit my comment: If you work with the assumption that $f$ is linear, i.e. $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$, you can easily solve it normally as $f(x)=Ae^x-f(1)$ and substituting $x=1$ you get $f(1)=\frac{Ae}{2}$. Then you find $A$ with some initial condition.

Comment: @Jepsilon This is also a [delay differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation) whose solutions are well-known

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments 